# Senderbase Monitoring Plugin for Nagios

Tags: shell-script, php, nagios

I have downloaded the script from this [link](https://gist.github.com/danmilleruk/6216055). Whenever I run that script it shows me below output.

```
 #./senderbase 182.176.116.195
```

Output:

```
 [ERROR] No results given
```

Is there anyone help me regarding this script to get valid output?

Comment: What should be the desired output? and can you ping the ip?

Comment: That's my server's ip, output will be ip reputation status i.e good, poor...

Comment: The php script is apparently failing to get the DNS record back; what do you get from the command line with: `host -t txt 195.116.176.182.rf.senderbase.org` ?

Comment: I am getting `195.116.176.182.rf.senderbase.org descriptive text "-6.8"`

But for another ip its failing to get valid output, it shows no result.

Comment: What would be the reason that this ip `136.243.219.142` shown `[ERROR] No results given`

`host -t txt 142.219.243.136.rf.senderbase.org`  
Output:
`Host 142.219.243.136.rf.senderbase.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`
Even rdns is already set against this ip.